# Using library with lower build version in react native android app

Tags: android, react-native

I am writting a new react native android app, i need to listen to SMS for user verification in this. 
I am trying to use the following library for the same :

https://github.com/CentaurWarchief/react-native-android-sms-listener

Build is failing because of inconsistent build tool version
My project has build tool version '25.0.0' but the library has build tool version of '23.0.2'. Will i be able to use this in my Application ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not listen to SMS with native code. Because many android mobiles have forbidden such behavior for security issues. Let user read the SMS and input the verification string is the right way.

Comment: Which all mobiles have done that ? I have to read SMS for other use cases in my application.

Comment: Not all, but so many, you do not want your app working fine with few mobile, but not fine with other, do you?